# JFreeChart - Determine the moment when chart is not visible because of big amount of range axes

Tags: jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart library to create Chart. I need to present big amount of data on the same chart. Because of that I have many range axes descriptions. 
Unfortunately when there are too many range axes, chart is no longer visible. It is possible to make chart visible by calling this simple lines (Where plot is an XYPlot instance):

```
int axises = plot.getRangeAxisCount();
for (int i = 0; i < axises; i++) {
   plot.getRangeAxis(i).setVisible(false);
}
```

This simple portion of code hides all RangeAxes. After that code execution, chart does not have any description for range axes but it is visible.

But unfortunately I am unable to figure out how can I determine does the chart is visible or not during the processing time.

Information that is important to me is in:

```
chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getDataArea().getWidth()
```

But unfortunately I am performing many operations on the chart (for example zoom, move, etc.) and because of that I need to have this information everytime, when state of the chart changes. I am unable to take that information whenever plotChanged() method of the PlotChangeListener interface is called, because there is no plot (this event is not fired). chartChanged() method from ChartChangeListener is fired too early - chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getDataArea().getWidth() returns old values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [`ChartProgressListener`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/event/ChartProgressListener.html) to the `ChartPanel`.

```
chart.addProgressListener(new ChartProgressListener() {

    @Override
    public void chartProgress(ChartProgressEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getType() + " "
            + event.getPercent() + " "
            + chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo()
                .getPlotInfo().getDataArea().getWidth());
    }
});
```